# cuda-gdb run error:"Failed to read the valid warps mask(dev=0,sm=0,error=16)"

Tags: cuda

I have correctly installed CUDA 6.0 on my Ubuntu12.04 and a sample `vectorAdd.cu` has passed in Nsight Eclipse:

```
  /**
 * Copyright 1993-2014 NVIDIA Corporation.  All rights reserved.
 *
 * Please refer to the NVIDIA end user license agreement (EULA) associated
 * with this source code for terms and conditions that govern your use of
 * this software. Any use, reproduction, disclosure, or distribution of
 * this software and related documentation outside the terms of the EULA
 * is strictly prohibited.
 *
 */

/**
 * Vector addition: C = A + B.
 *
 * This sample is a very basic sample that implements element by element
 * vector addition. It is the same as the sample illustrating Chapter 2
 * of the programming guide with some additions like error checking.
 */

#include <stdio.h>

// For the CUDA runtime routines (prefixed with "cuda_")
#include <cuda_runtime.h>

/**
 * CUDA Kernel Device code
 *
 * Computes the vector addition of A and B into C. The 3 vectors have the same
 * number of elements numElements.
 */
__global__ void
vectorAdd(const float *A, const float *B, float *C, int numElements)
{
    int i = blockDim.x * blockIdx.x + threadIdx.x;

    if (i < numElements)
    {
        C[i] = A[i] + B[i];
        C[i] = C[i] + 1;
    }

}

/**
 * Host main routine
 */
int
main(void)
{
    // Error code to check return values for CUDA calls
    cudaError_t err = cudaSuccess;

    // Print the vector length to be used, and compute its size
    int numElements = 50000;
    size_t size = numElements * sizeof(float);
    printf("[Vector addition of %d elements]\n", numElements);

    // Allocate the host input vector A
    float *h_A = (float *)malloc(size);

    // Allocate the host input vector B
    float *h_B = (float *)malloc(size);

    // Allocate the host output vector C
    float *h_C = (float *)malloc(size);

    // Verify that allocations succeeded
    if (h_A == NULL || h_B == NULL || h_C == NULL)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Failed to allocate host vectors!\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    // Initialize the host input vectors
    for (int i = 0; i < numElements; ++i)
    {
        h_A[i] = rand()/(float)RAND_MAX;
        h_B[i] = rand()/(float)RAND_MAX;
    }

    // Allocate the device input vector A
    float *d_A = NULL;
    err = cudaMalloc((void **)&d_A, size);

    if (err != cudaSuccess)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Failed to allocate device vector A (error code %s)!\n", cudaGetErrorString(err));
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    // Allocate the device input vector B
    float *d_B = NULL;
    err = cudaMalloc((void **)&d_B, size);

    if (err != cudaSuccess)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Failed to allocate device vector B (error code %s)!\n", cudaGetErrorString(err));
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    // Allocate the device output vector C
    float *d_C = NULL;
    err = cudaMalloc((void **)&d_C, size);

    if (err != cudaSuccess)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Failed to allocate device vector C (error code %s)!\n", cudaGetErrorString(err));
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    // Copy the host input vectors A and B in host memory to the device input vectors in
    // device memory
    printf("Copy input data from the host memory to the CUDA device\n");
    err = cudaMemcpy(d_A, h_A, size, cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);

    if (err != cudaSuccess)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Failed to copy vector A from host to device (error code %s)!\n", cudaGetErrorString(err));
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    err = cudaMemcpy(d_B, h_B, size, cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);

    if (err != cudaSuccess)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Failed to copy vector B from host to device (error code %s)!\n", cudaGetErrorString(err));
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    // Launch the Vector Add CUDA Kernel
    int threadsPerBlock = 256;
    int blocksPerGrid =(numElements + threadsPerBlock - 1) / threadsPerBlock;
    printf("CUDA kernel launch with %d blocks of %d threads\n", blocksPerGrid, threadsPerBlock);
    vectorAdd<<<blocksPerGrid, threadsPerBlock>>>(d_A, d_B, d_C, numElements);
    err = cudaGetLastError();

    if (err != cudaSuccess)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Failed to launch vectorAdd kernel (error code %s)!\n", cudaGetErrorString(err));
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    // Copy the device result vector in device memory to the host result vector
    // in host memory.
    printf("Copy output data from the CUDA device to the host memory\n");
    err = cudaMemcpy(h_C, d_C, size, cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);

    if (err != cudaSuccess)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Failed to copy vector C from device to host (error code %s)!\n", cudaGetErrorString(err));
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    // Verify that the result vector is correct
    for (int i = 0; i < numElements; ++i)
    {
        if (fabs(h_A[i] + h_B[i] - h_C[i]) > 1e-5)
        {
            fprintf(stderr, "Result verification failed at element %d!\n", i);
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
    }

    printf("Test PASSED\n");

    // Free device global memory
    err = cudaFree(d_A);

    if (err != cudaSuccess)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Failed to free device vector A (error code %s)!\n", cudaGetErrorString(err));
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    err = cudaFree(d_B);

    if (err != cudaSuccess)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Failed to free device vector B (error code %s)!\n", cudaGetErrorString(err));
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    err = cudaFree(d_C);

    if (err != cudaSuccess)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Failed to free device vector C (error code %s)!\n", cudaGetErrorString(err));
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    // Free host memory
    free(h_A);
    free(h_B);
    free(h_C);

    // Reset the device and exit
    // cudaDeviceReset causes the driver to clean up all state. While
    // not mandatory in normal operation, it is good practice.  It is also
    // needed to ensure correct operation when the application is being
    // profiled. Calling cudaDeviceReset causes all profile data to be
    // flushed before the application exits
    err = cudaDeviceReset();

    if (err != cudaSuccess)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Failed to deinitialize the device! error=%s\n", cudaGetErrorString(err));
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    printf("Done\n");
    return 0;
}
```

When I tried to use cuda-gdb to debug this program(CUDA device is GT240), Ctrl+Alt+F1 and close X11 using`sudo service lightdm stop`.
Compile the source file using:

```
nvcc -g -G vectorAdd.cu -o vectorAdd -gencode arch=compute_12,code=sm_12
```

Then enter debug using:

```
$ cuda-gdb vectorAdd
NVIDIA (R) CUDA Debugger
6.0 release
Portions Copyright (C) 2007-2014 NVIDIA Corporation
GUN gdb (GDB) 7.6
Copyright (C) 2013 Free SoftWare Foundation, Inc.
Licnese GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/license/gpl.html>
This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law. Type "show copying" and "show warranty" for details.
This GDB was configured as "x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu".
For bug reporting instructions, please see:
<http://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/bugs/>...
Reading symbols from /home/<username>/cuda-workspace/SampleForGDB/src/vectorAdd...done
(cuda-gdb) break 131
Breakpoint 1 at 0x402814: file vectorAdd.cu line, 131.
(cuda-gdb) run
Staring program: /home/<username>/cuda-workspace/SampleForGDB/src/vectorAdd
[Thread debugging using libthread_db enable]
Using host libthread_db library: "/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libthread_db.so.1".
[Vector addition of 50000 elements]
Error: Failed to read the vaild warps mask (dev=0, sm=0, error=16)
```

Even I didn't set the breakpoint, the same error happened. And I enter`(cuda-gdb)info cuda devices` ,it shows "No Devices" although I get correct result by run `./deviceQueryDrv` under cuda_samples/bin.

Comment: Is the GPU you are using also a display device?

Comment: Yes. But isn't it used as a cuda device after sudo service lightdm stop?

Comment: Yes, that should be OK. This is actually a bug in cuda-gdb. There is a workaround in the linked duplicate answer, otherwise upgrade to CUDA 6.5 and it should be fixed